# Tasks highlights in comments (C#) stopped working after updating to VisualStudio 8.1 on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-mac

After I've updated to new Visual Studio version 8.1 on Mac - task highlights stopped working. I mean tasks (like "TODO", "FIXME" etc.) that were highlighted (pink in default color theme) in my comments in C#, now they are just gray like all  the other comment text.

Who also updated to VS 8.1 on Mac, can you please tell, do you have same issue? (or maybe for some reason they just disabled it on purpose in the new version?) Or your tasks highlights work fine after updating to 8.1?

Tried everything and did not find any similar issues on internet. I liked those highlights so much... :(

P.S. Also in the Tasks window task list, the "Go to Task" function don't work too.

Comment: maybe it's a bug, try to ask this guy " ***Cody Beyer*** " @cobey. He publishes the preview on the Microsoft website [ https://github.com/cobey ] on Microsoft website [ https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-for-mac-version-8-1-preview-1/ ]

Comment: Go to Preferences > Environment > Tasks like [ https://imgur.com/RVsgnE6 ] and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Microsoft forum Cody Beyer (the guy from Microsoft) helped me to fix the problem.

You need to revert to the old editor. You can do so by opening "Visual Studio > Preferences > Text Editor > General" and uncheck "Open C# files in the New Editor".

So this is a bug in their C# "New Editor" (which was set as default for everyone in v8.1). Seems that we need to wait until they fix the "New Editor" to use it, if we want task highlights.

[Link to issue on Microsoft forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/608504/tasks-highlights-in-comments-c-stopped-working-aft.html)